# Access the static contents which is out of the application server scope

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat

In Spring how to access the files which is out side the web server application folder means which is reside on any drive like C:\STATIC_RESOURCES\images\abc.jpg ?

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC?  Do you mean, you want a url that maps to an external folder?

Comment: That's not a good idea

Comment: Spring *is* Java, isn't it? Did you try searching at all? "java read file" etc.?

Comment: @Dave actually i want to access the static content from my file system inside the JSP pages means the content which are out side the scope of server.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery why is not good idea, i think it is good because several times we have some static contents such as images,common js/css files etc which is common for all applications....if we don't follow this then we may have to redeploy the applications on every minor changes is made on the static contents if we keep the static contents inside the application folder.

Comment: @kryger actually i want to access the images on my jsp pages, it is accessible through the jav Fli System but not able to access it on jsp pages.                                                                                                             for this i tried to add the below code inside the <Host> tag of server.xml file of apache tomcat but still am not able to access it  <Context docBase="C:\STATIC_RESOURCES\images" path="/Spring4Test/images"/> to access a image which is in my c drive having the path C:\STATIC_RESOURCES\images\test_image.jpg

Comment: So you want links to images where the images are stored outside of your web application?  What web/application server are you using?

Comment: @Dave exactly that i wants..you got my point...m using Apache Tomcat web server..plz let me know if you have solution for this...i am waiting for the solution.

Comment: @Naveen, it looks like you are doing it right.  Can you give an example of the URL of your application and then the URL in your img tag?  This might help track down what is going wrong.

Comment: @Dave it resolved now actually i was doing the right..means adding of Context tag in server.xml inside the Host tag this was absolutely correct configuration...but as i was doing the changes on server.xml which resides inside Apache Server directory...but as i am using Eclipse IDE so it takes control over our Apache server...so if we want to access from Eclipse then the Context tag should be added in server.xml which reside inside Eclipse IDE and if we want to access using WAR file then make the changes in server.xml file which is in our actual Apache Server directory.